# GreenDAO clears cache randomly

Tags: android, caching, greendao

I´ve got two buttons in an Android activity with these two methods attached. One of them loads data and another just retrive it. Of course, the first time I execute the second method it gets data from cache and consumed time is very low, but further calls to this method always becomes in bigger times (as bigs as the consumed by the load data method), in other words, it seems that cache clears "randomly".

daoSession is an static attribute and I just call several times the getDataFromCacheById method (press the same button repeteadly, nothing else). Why does it clears cache? Is there any way to keep the cache data in memory always?

Best regards

```
public void onMyLoadButtonClick(View view) {
        listaIds.clear();
        List<String> lTexto = new ArrayList<String>();
        Date iniTime = new Date();

        LibroDao libroDao = daoSession.getLibroDao();

        for (Libro tempLibro : libroDao.loadAll()) {
            for (Nota tempNota : tempLibro.getNotaList()) {
                lTexto.add(tempNota.getText());
                listaIds.add(tempNota.getId());
            }
        }

        Date finTime = new Date();
        long tiempoTotal = finTime.getTime() - iniTime.getTime();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Overall time = " + tiempoTotal + " lTextoSize = " + lTexto.size());
    }

    public void getDataFromCacheById(View view) {
        List<String> lTexto2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Date iniTime2 = new Date();

        for (Long tempId : listaIds) {
            lTexto2.add(noteDao.load(tempId).getText());
        }

        Date finTime2 = new Date();
        long tiempoTotal2 = finTime2.getTime() - iniTime2.getTime();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Tiempo total de la operación Prueba Caché = " + tiempoTotal2  + " lTextoSize = " + lTexto2.size());
    }
```